# Unable to add apple device in Android studio

Tags: ios, iphone, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to try out the Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) in Android studio. I have installed the Plugin and when I try to add configuration for IOS, nothing shows up. I just have an IOS option but nothing shows up when I click on it. The android device is already set up, so I was able to run it in Android.

[image]

Comment: Are you running AS on macOS. Otherwise you cannot use simulators. If you create the project with KMM plugin it's weired that you don't have the run configuration for iOS already set up, but you can try to click on the + button on the upper-left corner.

Comment: I'm running AS on Windows 10.... will apple ever stop with this BS of using only mac for development?

Comment: I guess this would come in remote future [-; But who knows... maybe Apple could leave us speechless with an unexpected move XD

Comment: I post our findings as an answer for future readers.

Comment: even on my macbook same issue exists.

Comment: I am not able to start a project in AS in windows. How were you able to start the project?

Comment: @Parth maybe they've made some changes recently. This was long back and kmm was in beta.. idk if it's still in beta but changes keep happening during beta releases. so if you're serious about stable multi platform, I'd recommend flutter for now.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are not running Android Studio on **macOS**. You must have macOS to compile through *XCode* and use Apple *Simulators*.

If you are running AS on macOS and you created the project with KMM plugin it's weird that you don't have the run configuration for iOS already set up, but you can try to click on the `+` button on the upper-left corner. Remember that you must have *XCode* (and *Simulators*) and *command line tools* installed on your machine.

If you are running AS on an OS different from macOS you can only compile the non native (not macOS or iOS) part of the library.

Comment: I use windows 10. I get it. I am poor and I can't afford apple products. nvm

Comment: I am using Apple MAcbook and still have the same issue. Cannot See any configuration. The AS kind of hangs when I click on IOS Application in Add Configurations dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. What fixed it it for me was installing Xcode command line tools with `xcode-select --install`.
If that doesn't work, generally check the integrity of your Xcode setup.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: No, there is no Xcode on windows (at least not without considerable workarounds)